# Is there a GUI application for adjusting monitor color?

Tags: gui, colors, color-management

I have an Asus laptop with an i5 processor, and an nVidia 610m graphics card, and an external monitor that is slightly pink. It was easy to fix this with the Windows control panel.

Seeing that Ubuntu lacks a GUI for color adjustment/calibration I searched for the nVidia driver in hopes that I could use its control panel but my card, like many others, isn't supported (for Linux).

I was able to import my old `.icc` profile from Windows but it's pretty useless to me now unless I can adjust it.

And as fantastic as command-line is, color adjustment is something that *really*, ***really*** should be done with a GUI.

**Are there any applications out there that can create/adjust ICC profiles?**

Are there any applications that can simply adjust the monitor colors?

Comment: If you install NVidia's drivers you get their NVidia X-Server Settings app and there you can adjust monitor colours. Those drivers are kind of unstable and hang X sometimes, but it works for me with GF 8600M.

Comment: I did that, but (since my card isn't supported?) the Settings app doesn't do anything - certainly no option to adjust color. What it did do was ask that I edit my config file to make it work and all that did was leave me stranded with 2 640x480 monitors :(

Answer (score 1):

Your card is supported by nvidia legacy drivers and the gui for color works fine there.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly** try installing from Additional Drivers in Dash (version ***current-updates***)I can't remember how I did my NVidia install on Ubuntu, but am pretty sure it worked with this otion.

I also ran it manually following a guide (on Suse) but on Ubuntu it worked straight away (if you do it in non-X run-level) by installing additional drivers. If it's really important to you, back-up your system and work away. Some links:

Community Ubuntu Documentation [HOW-TO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

[NVidia download page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) Where you can download drivers and check if your card is supported. As Arup says it is (it looks like, G610M is supported), but you can double check by running in terminal:

`sudo lshw -c video | grep product`

and compare with the list they provide (claim ;). Just make sure you install the proper one, preferably Legacy (304) version.

[Here's another how-to](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu.html) - read it and especially comments (cause it looks familiar to me).

Hope you'll manage.

Comment: Thanks to both of you but I had to abandon Ubuntu for Windows because my Adobe-based workload is still pretty heavy and something as simple as adjusting monitor color shouldn't take days of digging through forums. Maybe I'll be back some time. I mostly liked it, and I really hate Windows, so I'll be back I guess, at some point.

Comment: That's pretty much why I keep Windows - for simple RAW work. It is "unfortunate", but hey... Wait 10 years and you'll see! ;) Obviously you should blame the vendor rather than Linux/GNU community.

Comment: Oh absolutely! I know all about the drama NVIDIA has caused for Linux. No way I'm waiting ten years. I'll see you guys soon enough.